# Multiple ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter's in Netty pipleline

Tags: java, netty

I'm quite new with netty, I want to create a TCP server which does a custom application layer handshaking when a connection is to be instantiated. After the handshaking I want to pass the messages (ByteBuf) to a queue so that they could be processed by some other threads.

My question is, can I have multiple ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter's in the channel pipeline? one for  the application layer handshaking protocol and the other one for passing the message to the queue. Furthermore I want to know how the messages flow through the pipeline. If a message is received at one handler (or decoder/encoder) how is it passed to another handler.

Specifically, if I change the EchoServer from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/master/src/main/java/com/manning/nettyinaction/chapter2/EchoServerHandler.java) and add another ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter, the echo server handler would stop receiving any messages.

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) 
                     throws Exception {
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                     @Override
                     public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                          Object msg) {
                           }
                          });

                  ch.pipeline().addLast(
                       new EchoServerHandler());
                 }
                 });
```

My logic is: have 2 ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter's then do the handshaking with the first handler and discard packets if they do not match the handshaking criteria, and then pass the messages to a queue through the second ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter. Is my logic correct? If not how should it be?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` is an adapter class to the `ChannelInBoundHandler` interface. For beginning you can use `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` (or more complicated you can extend the adapter class writing your own handler that extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` ).
The `SimpleCHannelInboundHandler` releases the message automatically after `channelRead()` (and thereby passes it to the next handler in the ChannelPipeline).

For using the easier `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` see this thread [Netty hello world example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419433/netty-hello-world-example-not-working)

So instead of this `ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {}`

you have to write a new class that extends `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` like

```
public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler{


    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {


        try {
            System.out.println(in.toString(io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
        } finally {
            in.release();
        }


    }
}
```

and invoke it like

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyHandler());
                    }
```

As said above the `SimpleCHannelInboundHandler` releases the message automatically after channelRead() (and thereby passes it to the next handler in the ChannelPipeline).

If you use `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` you have to implement the passing of the message/event to the next handler yourself

**A handler has to invoke the event propagation methods in `ChannelHandlerContext ctx` to forward an event to its next handler.** (in the SimpleChannelInboundHandler class this is implemented yet)

```
 public class MyInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
       System.out.println("Connected!");
       ctx.fireChannelActive();
    }
 }
```

See this http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html

Comment: I still have some problems:

'    ch.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>() {

      protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf in = null; 
      try {
      in = (ByteBuf) (msg);
      in.retain();
      } finally {
      in.release();
      }
      }
      });
    ch.pipeline().addLast(
      new EchoServerHandler(channels));'

The EchoServerHandler is still not called

Comment: try not calling `finally{in.release()}` see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419433/netty-hello-world-example-not-working

Comment: I had the problem that the next inbound handler was not invoked; then I realized I had to call `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg)` instead of `ctx.writeAndFlush(msg)`, because the latter sends the message to the next outbound handler, not the next inbound handler.

Answer (score -1):

I must remind that:

**Only One SimpleChannelInboundHandler extention can be add to the pipeline chain.**
Because SimpleChannelInboundHandler have a finally code block will release all the msg.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    boolean release = true;
    try {
        if (acceptInboundMessage(msg)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            I imsg = (I) msg;
            channelRead0(ctx, imsg);
        } else {
            release = false;
            ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
        }
    } finally {
        if (autoRelease && release) {
            //release all handled messages,so the next handler won't be executed
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);**
        }
    }
}
```

Use ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter instead:

```
public class CustomizeChannelInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("do something you like!")

    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
  }
```

}