# Is there any better way to call a method from netty than implement methods inside the handler?

Tags: java, netty

This is a simple question. Netty seems to be a great tool for sending information between servers and clients. I want to send informations, and also events..or rather called instructions what do to.

```
public class PojoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        Message body = (Message) msg;
        logger.info("server read msg id:{}, body:{}", body.getId(), body.getBody());

        Message response = new Message();
        response.setId(1024);
        response.setFrom("server");
        response.setBody("hello from server");
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        logger.error("server caught exception", cause);
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

I have this code here and it describes a handler for a server. When the client send its message to the server. The method `channelRead` going to be called directly.

Is it smart to implements a `switch case` inside `channelRead` if I want to use other functions around my application, or can Netty do that in another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter's in Netty pipleline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075855/multiple-channelinboundhandleradapters-in-netty-pipleline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple handlers each doing a different task instead of having a switch case. You can simply call

```
ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
```

if you plan not to handle the message in a particular handler, then it will trigger the next handler in the pipeline.

Comment: So if I call that method. What will it do?

Comment: It will trigger the next handler. You can have different classes to handle different messages/ kinds of messages.

Comment: Yes. I know that if I call `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);` it fill call `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)`. But right now, I'm "standing" inside `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)`. So if I fire this call `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);` I will call the same method I'm into again? What if I add a new `ChannelPipeLine` like this `p.addLast(new PojoServerHandler(myClassObject));` with a argument `myClassObject`. Then from the `PojoServerHandler` class, I can use methods from `myClassObject` that are injected from the constructor of `PojoServerHandler` ?

Comment: Or do you mean that I need to add another pipeline handler?

Comment: It will not call the same `channelRead` method it will call the `channelRead` of the next handler. Yes you can add a new handler to handle a new task.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm starting to understand how it works. And if I want to send a new message, like a response back, when I enter the next pipeline. Do I need to have the encoder and decoder once again in the pipeline?

Comment: It is the next handler in the same pipeline. You don't need to add encoders and decoders again.